# Django - MongoDb - How can I use ModelForms?

Tags: django, mongodb, django-forms

I'm using Django and MongoDB with MongoEngine. I'm creating a customized backend and like to use - like in plain Django - ModelForms to save time.

Any ideas if and what plugin I can use? Or how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [django-mongodbforms](https://github.com/jschrewe/django-mongodbforms). The author claims to be more or less 100% compatible with Django's `ModelForm`s.

Comment: not documentented but you can install it via pip: `pip install mongodbforms`

Comment: and you need to change the import path from objectId in `mongodbforms/fields.py` to `bson.objectid`